# Next.JS + Sanity. Hydration Error when including Time Stamp

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sanity, hydration

Anyone have an answer to this? I am receiving a hydration error whenever I include a timestamp fetched from Sanity. Here's the way it is expressed on the page.

```
     <p className="font-extralight text-sm">
          Post by <span className="text-blue-500">{post.author.name}</span>{" "}
          Published at {new Date(post._createdAt).toLocaleString()}
        </p>
```

The page seems to render fine but the hydration error is annoying. Removing this line gets rid of the hydration error. I am using SSR and ISR on the this app as well if that is helpful.

Comment: The issue comes from the server and the client having different timezones. Using UTC will avoid this. If you don't want to use UTC, you can try to add `suppressHydrationWarning` to the `p` element.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `suppressHydrationWarning` property to the element which renders something that might produce mismatch, like a date in your case.

It only works one level deep. Don’t overuse it, it is intended to be used as an escape hatch.

[More in the docs](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot#suppressing-unavoidable-hydration-mismatch-errors)

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert your date server side (in page.tsx if your using v13.4+) with `new Date(post._createdAt).toLocaleString()` so when it gets passed to the client there is no mismatch.